# Website not woking after clone it from my own github account

Tags: git, github

I make my website and push it on Gihub and delate it from my pc permanently. Now I need to change some staff on it that's why I clone it and now it not working.
The inputs are not event working as well as the button and navigation bar.

I tried pull/clone it from git terminal but website not works.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you haven't added all the required code or maybe you hardcoded an absolute URL or any other factor that could be causing the problem you're experiencing.

To tackle this issue, the most effective approach would be to debug the website using devtools.

In case you're struggling to resolve the issue or errors, just update your question with the problem you're facing so that you can get the necessary help to fix it.